# Escape log file as a json string for use in REST call using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a log file with all kind of character that need escaping, quote, double quote, forward and backward slashes, URL, other jsons.

I want to send this file as part of REST request which is in JSON format, how do I escape my file in Python to be ready for transporting.

Example of my file:

```
(12/5/2020 8:20:39 PM) My Project: Log directory created
(12/5/2020 8:20:43 PM) My Project: SF auth result: {vOPDetail,},{vOPResponseCode,},{vOPState,success},{vOutputToken,00D4W},{vOpResponseBody,},{vOPType,},{vOPInstanceUrl,https://test.my.salesforce.com}
(12/5/2020 8:20:43 PM) My Project: Token: "00D4W0000"
(12/5/2020 8:20:43 PM) My Project: URL: https://test.my.salesforce.com
```

My REST call look like this:

```
PATCH https://test.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/My_Object/a2P4W00000272ujUAA

Body

{
    "My_Namespace__My_Object__c" : "$Log$"
}
```

Where $Log$ is where the log file will go

The actual REST call is in another language, I just need PYTHON to escape the log file to be ready for transport.  Here is what I tried and does NOT work:

```
import json
def EscapeJSONString(input):
    return json.dumps(input)
```

The input here is the entirely of the log file which is read using a different language, due to my circumstances I can not escape the log file in the other language, I can just read it as is.

The other language just call this python function EscapeJSONString and provide the log as input and then save the output to a variable.

Comment: What is `input` here? How are you reading the file into that object?

Comment: The input is the entirely of the log file which is read using a different language, due to my circumstances I can not escape the log file in the other language, I can just read it as is.

Comment: Please show the value of `input` and your code that reads the file. `json.dumps({"log": log.read()})` should work fine.

Comment: _input here is the entirely of the log file which is read using a different language_ ... Then how are you **calling** this python function?

Comment: There is already a partial example of the log file in the description, I can not show the entire log file since it's very long.  It's exactly as I have it in the example with no processing done.

Comment: I am calling python in the other language.  It have the ability to call and run python function, however there is no built in functionality to escape the string.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you would have the ability to make HTTP calls and create a subprocess but not be able to create an escaped string

Comment: Such is the life of corporate drone eh?  It's a visual language that's as useful as a toddler doing programming.  It is possible to do my own escaping using string replace but that's such a pain in this particular language I don't want to do it.  Which is why I am trying to do this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping from a language to the other just to escape a string doesn't sound like the best solution. Transfering a large log file this way also seems very inefficient, why not skip REST for this specific call and have an HTTP request to get the log in it's raw format.

But if you want to do it this way, `json.dumps()` does the escaping you need for string variables as values, so you can build en entire json like so:

```
import json
def EscapeJSONString(input):
    return json.dumps({"My_Namespace__My_Object__c": input})
```

Comment: It actually worked!  A surprise to be sure, but a welcome one.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what `input` is here, but you need to mention how this function actually gets executed, because the file content does get properly escaped if read directly in Python

Note: Forward slashes and brackets don't need escaped

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('/tmp/data.txt') as f:
...     print(json.dumps({"log": f.read()}))
... )
...
{"log": "(12/5/2020 8:20:39 PM) My Project: Log directory created\n(12/5/2020 8:20:43 PM) My Project: SF auth result: {vOPDetail,},{vOPResponseCode,},{vOPState,success},{vOutputToken,00D4W},{vOpResponseBody,},{vOPType,},{vOPInstanceUrl,https://test.my.salesforce.com}\n(12/5/2020 8:20:43 PM) My Project: Token: \"00D4W0000\"\n(12/5/2020 8:20:43 PM) My Project: URL: https://test.my.salesforce.com\n"}
```

Assuming `input` is a string, then you'd be returning a string, not a JSON object for the HTTP body

Comment: The file is read in another language so I can't show it here because it is a drag and drop language.  But trust me, it's read exactly as is shown in the example and then passed in it's entirely as input to the file.  I can't read the file from Python unfortunately.

Comment: My question is: What _type_ of data is `input`? A dictionary? Or a string? In the first case, you get back a JSON object (as a string), in the later, you _will_ get an escaped string of the input

Comment: It's one giant string.

Comment: In other words, `f.read()` here is the content being based. Shouldn't matter how it is gotten.

Comment: I can't use f.read() since I can't read a file in python due to project limitation, trust me I wouldn't use the other language if I had a choice.  I have no choice in the matter.

Comment: Like the other answer shows, your `input` is my `f.read()`. Your initial question seemed misguided because the string ***is*** escaped, but seems you wanted a JSON object instead